# Gulp js stuck on "Starting 'watch'"

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch

Saving the file does not save the changes made on localhost only until I build again.
I'm on a fork where the other people using the same upstream do not encounter this issue. I reinstalled gulp, npm, node tried multiple versions - nothing works. Unfortunately, I have no clue what part of the script is messing this up so I can't include a snippet.

https://github.com/Miodec/monkeytype/blob/master/gulpfile.js

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have only create the **watch** task but didn't run it in your **build** command.
You need to add the **watch** task in your **build** command.
See the code below.

task("build", series("clean", "compile", "watch"));